# Find if values exists in an array of object (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, iteration

I am having a hard time trying to get this right. I would be glad if someone could help me get a solution for this.

```
0: Object
   Name: Ria
   Age: 27
   Sex: Female

1: Object
   Name: Brian
   Age: 23
   Sex: Male

2: Object
   Name: Rick
   Age: 32
   Sex: Male
```

Here is the array of objects. I am passing a user entered value. for e.g. I ask the user to enter the name. Once entered, i need to check in the above array of objects, if the Name is present in the array of objects.

I tried a variety of solutions using foreach, basic array itereation and i couldnot find a way.

Here is what i tried at the last...

```
var result = false;

function search(nameKey, myArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].Name === nameKey) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

result = search($scope.data.name, checkdatabase);
```

Here, `checkdatabase` is the array of objects and `$scope.data.name` is the user entered value. I am expecting the value of result as `true` when user is present in database or else result as `false` which is defined initially.

Comment: You are checking `myArray[i].User_ID`, but your objects have no `User_ID` property. You probably want to check `myArray[i].Name`.

Comment: sorry. corrected tat attribute.

Comment: Just add `return false;` at the end of the function

Comment: @AlonEitan Why? By default it will return `undefined` which is falsy.

Comment: Have you tried testing this in browser and setting a breakpoint so that you can verify values?

Comment: @MikeC You're correct of course, but that `var result = false;` is useless in this case, and I like my functions returning consistent value types (boolean in this case)

Comment: @AlonEitan I think it's a good idea to return consistent value types but that doesn't solve the problem and is pointless to the discussion. And `result = false` just means it has a default value of `false`. Generally a good indicator that you intend to use it as a bool.

Comment: @MikeC Oh, in that case I just didn't understand the question. That `result = false` is outside the function's scope and that was the cause for my confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
result = myArray.some(function(user) { return user.name === $scope.data.name; });
```

BTW, this is just a suggestion: I would store an index of user names and use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Whenever you add an user, you can add the name to an array:

```
var userNameIndex = [];
var users = [];

users.push(user);
// I've called .toLowerCase() so the index isn't case sensitive
userNameIndex.push(user.Name.toLowerCase().trim());
```

...and you can check if the user has been already added as follows:

```
// I've called .toLowerCase() to perform a case insensitive search
var result = userNameIndex.indexOf($scope.data.name.toLowerCase().trim()) > -1;
```

It should perform better if you're retrieving a lot of users.

> I am expecting the value of result as true when user is present in
>   database or else result as false which is defined initially.

Yes, but note that calling `search` sets the variable `result` again. That is, the initial `false` is never preserved.

Comment: This really isn't any different from his own solution, so clearly there must be some other issue.

Comment: @Comptonburger Are you sure? It's not the same returning `false` than `undefined`, is it?

Comment: The author's pointed out in the comments that he doesn't care if it returns `false` or `undefined`. His question almost certainly has some other issue, making this not the answer.

Comment: @Comptonburger Since we don't know more details about the actual issue, I would say that working with booleans is better than relying on `undefined` as `false`. Check that the OP is using `===` instead of `==`. Just imagine if OP is using also `===` on bindings.

Comment: @Comptonburger In the other hand, I don't find where the OP says he/she doesn't care about the result at all.........

Comment: @Comptonburger- there is definitely some other issue. the debugger shows that it executed ---- var result = userNameIndex.indexOf($scope.data.name) > -1; ----- but everytime it gives a false value

Comment: @anjaligupte is `$scope.data.name` an string?

Comment: Yes its a string Matias

Comment: @anjaligupte and have you checked that `userNameIndex` has the names, and do you want a case sensitive or insensitive search? ;)

Comment: userNameIndex has the name which i am looking for. I type 'Raven' at user end and 'Raven' is saved in database.

Comment: @anjaligupte So I doubt that `some` or `indexOf` would be returning `false`...

Comment: when i do  a console of Object.Name, it returns undefined. Whereas, if i do console.log(object), it gives me an array of objects

Comment: @anjaligupte Can you paste here as a comment the code to get this output?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer- if i do a console like------>>Array.Name, i get result as undefined. if i do Array[0].Name, i get the result as 'Ria'

Comment: @anjaligupte And is it strange that? Name isn't a property of `Array`, but of the objects stored in the array!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: yea. i think it is. Its a part of object stored in the array. and i need to find that part from each objects... which are present inside the array

Comment: @anjaligupte You're wrong and the first step to solve the issue yourself is understanding that. Array has properties like `length`. `name` is a property of an object stored in an index of the array

Comment: @anjaligupte I believe you need to double-check my answer and understand it *as is* and you need to do it from scratch. I mean, I feel that you've a chaos in your mind right now :) Take your time and don't try to copy-paste my code but **you need to understand it**.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer- the console.log of the array of objects has the same structure as the one mentioned in the questions. i am not understanding where i am going wrong

Comment: @anjaligupte When you say "I do a console.log of Array.Name" I get scared ;D

Comment: atleast i could scare you. :D i will have a look at your answer and understand what is going on

Comment: @anjaligupte Now I need to go to bed... It's too late here. So... I'll check your comments tomorrow, BTW I feel that the problem is just how you're using the sample code of my answer... Probably a very small effort more will drive you to solve the issue yourself (which is always better because it'll mean that you've advanced in your JS knowledge!)

Comment: how silly of me. object.name had empty white spaces in it. hence it was not giving true value even if the name was same.

Comment: @anjaligupte and did you notice that while we were chatting yesterday I edited my answer to call ‘trim‘ function to avoid white spaces surrounding the whole names? :D

Comment: @anjaligupte Calling `trim()` is a very good practice when you're dealing with user input

Answer (score 0):

To extend Matias' answer, `some` is great for the job as long as you don't need the item that matches your predicate. `some` accepts a context as a second argument:

```
result = myArray.some(function(user) { 
  return user.name === this.name; 
}, $scope.data); //pass $scope.data as this
```

If your want to keep track of the item that matches the predicates, you have several options: Create an object of indexes or iterate over the array using `forEach` or `while`

```
var index = myArray.map(function(item) { 
  return item.name;          
}).indexOf(nameKey);
var item = myArray[index];

var l = myArray.length;
var found = false;
while(!found && l--) {
  found = myArray[l].name === nameKey;
}
var item = myArray[l];
```

Comment: Matias :D Not Mathias!!

Answer (score 0):

use  lodash.js. you can filter the array with given parameter.

For Example :

```
var givenJson ={ Name: Ria,Age: 27,Sex: Female};// this is the whole array
var response= _.filter(givenJson, function(data){ 
   return data.name == "Ria";
}); 
if(response != null && response != undefined){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is very sad. You suggest a library when filtering is part of array prototype since many years....

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer http://colintoh.com/blog/lodash-10-javascript-utility-functions-stop-rewriting.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand my previous comment... I'm telling you that there're many array functions that are part of the ECMA-Script 5.x standard since many years and `Array.prototype.filter` is already in vanilla javascript. Your advise about using lodash doesn't provide more value to already published answers...